# What can I infer about the eigenvalues of the sum of two matrices with known eigendecompositons

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I have two matrices and I know the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of both, it also happens to be the case that they share the same set of eigenvalues. I now need to sum the two matrices and take the average, and finally, I need to compute the eigenvalues of the average matrix. Is there any shortcut I can take to perform the last step without digaonlization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless one of the matrices happens to be scalar (i.e. only one eigenvalue, and eigenvectors form a basis), knowing the eigendecompositions of two matrices is hardly of any help.

Consider this example: let $A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{pmatrix}$ with eigenvalues $1$ and $2$, and let $B$ be the same matrix, but in another basis, say rotated by $\varphi$: $B=\begin{pmatrix}1+\sin(\varphi)^2 & \sin(\varphi)\cos(\varphi) \\ 
\sin(\varphi)\cos(\varphi) & 1+\cos(\varphi)^2\end{pmatrix}$. You can check that $B$ has eigenvalues $1$ and $2$ corresponding to eigenvectors $\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\varphi) \\ -\sin(\varphi)\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}\sin(\varphi) \\ \cos(\varphi)\end{pmatrix}$.

Now, the characteristic polynomial of $\frac{A+B}{2}$ is $\lambda^2-3\lambda+2+\frac{\sin(\varphi)^2}{4}$, with discriminant $D=1-\sin(\varphi)^2$, so eigenvalues are $\frac{3\pm\sqrt{1-\sin(\varphi)^2}}{2}$, which can be anything between $1$ and $2$.

Note that for $\varphi=0$ we get $A=B$, while for $\varphi=\frac{\pi}{2}$ we get $B=\begin{pmatrix}2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\frac{A+B}{2}=\frac{3}{2}I$.

---

In general, although there does exist rich theory concerning the structure of a single matrix/operator (everything about eigenvalues & eigenvectors), it is in general extremely difficult to get something similar for a pair of matrices (unless you know something else about them, e.g. that [they commute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix#Simultaneous_diagonalization)). Problems that involve classification of pairs of matrices up to change of basis are even called [wild](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wild_problem).